# Error after deploying the application in appspot

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I get the following error in the browser when trying to access my Java application in appspot.

```
Error: NOT_FOUND
```

However it works fine when I run from Eclipse or ant. I have checked the logs in GAE admin console but couldn't find any error messages.

I have also tried by removing all the *.class files before building.

The application is deployed using the appcfg script provided in appengine-java-sdk-1.5.3. Is there any specific reason for this behaviour?

Here is the debug messages from GAE log console:

```
2011-10-02 22:11:39.306 / 302 14950ms 10348cpu_ms 315api_cpu_ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.186 Safari/535.1
115.119.214.18 - - [02/Oct/2011:22:11:39 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 191 - "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.186 Safari/535.1" "xxxxxxxx-test.appspot.com" ms=14950 cpu_ms=10348 api_cpu_ms=315 cpm_usd=0.287514 loading_request=1 throttle_code=1 instance=00c61b117c46324075b13d0c2ce04f5678c813
I 2011-10-02 22:11:26.447
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
W 2011-10-02 22:11:26.728
[s~xxxxxxxx-test/8.353561328003056299].<stderr>: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).

W 2011-10-02 22:11:26.728
[s~xxxxxxxx-test/8.353561328003056299].<stderr>: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

I 2011-10-02 22:11:37.075
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
I 2011-10-02 22:11:39.306
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5">

<filter>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <context-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/*.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <listener>
                <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/ExampleApp/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <welcome-file-list>
                <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Contents of index.jsp (welcome-file)

```
<% response.sendRedirect("/ExampleApp/user/login"); %>
```

Here is the build.xml:

```
<project>
    <property name="sdk.dir" location="../appengine-java-sdk-1.5.3" />
    <import file="${sdk.dir}/config/user/ant-macros.xml" />

    <path id="project.classpath">
        <pathelement path="war/WEB-INF/classes" />
        <fileset dir="war/WEB-INF/lib">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${sdk.dir}/lib">
            <include name="shared/**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
<!--
    <target name="copyjars" description="Copies the App Engine JARs to the WAR.">
        <copy todir="war/WEB-INF/lib" flatten="true">
        <fileset dir="${sdk.dir}/lib/user">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
-->
    <target name="compile" description="Compiles Java source and copies other source files to the WAR.">
        <mkdir dir="war/WEB-INF/classes" />
        <copy todir="war/WEB-INF/classes">
            <fileset dir="src">
            <exclude name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="war/WEB-INF/classes" classpathref="project.classpath" debug="on" />
    </target>

    <target name="datanucleusenhance" depends="compile" description="Performs JDO enhancement on compiled data classes.">
        <enhance_war war="war" />
    </target>

    <target name="runserver" depends="datanucleusenhance" description="Starts the development server.">
        <dev_appserver war="war" />
    </target>

    <target name="update" depends="datanucleusenhance" description="Uploads the application to App Engine.">
        <appcfg action="update" war="war" />
    </target>

    <target name="update_indexes" depends="datanucleusenhance" description="Uploads just the datastore index configuration to App Engine.">
        <appcfg action="update_indexes" war="war" />
    </target>

    <target name="rollback" depends="datanucleusenhance" description="Rolls back an interrupted application update.">
        <appcfg action="rollback" war="war" />
    </target>

    <target name="request_logs" description="Downloads log data from App Engine for the application.">
        <appcfg action="request_logs" war="war">
        <options>
            <arg value="--num_days=5"/>
        </options>
        <args>
            <arg value="logs.txt"/>
        </args>
        </appcfg>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: I assume you're seeing that in your browser when you try your app's URL. Is that all you're seeing? Is there a stack trace of any sort?

Comment: Yes, the **Not found** is the only error message I can see in the browser. I have added the debug messages from GAE log console. The application is running without any problems in Eclipse and ant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that error isn't one of AppEngine's. Is it possible that some configuration bit of Spring isn't in your `war` folder?

Comment: May be you are right, but I'm wondering how is it working with Eclipse. If there is an issue in configuration, then it shouldn't work with Eclipse too.

Comment: What's visible to Eclipse may not match what's deployed. This could happen for a few reasons: Eclipse may have a wider classpath, something that should be a resource gets accidentally put in `static-files`, something that should be installed gets accidentally included in an `exclude`.

Comment: I have downloaded the war folder from appspot and compared the jar files. The appspot version is missing appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.3.jar. Is this an expected behaviour?

Comment: I also tried the dev_appserver.sh script in the appengine sdk and it works without any issues.

Comment: What version of the Google Plugin for Eclipse are you running?

Comment: I am using Eclipse-3.6 at my office but I rarely use it for deploying the app and I really don't write the code. I mostly use apache-ant to test run the app and deploy in appspot

Comment: My suspicion falls on the `build.xml` that you inherited.

Comment: Added build.xml to my question.

Answer (score 0):

After several days of tests and experiments, I got the solution for the problem in appspot.com. There was an issue with the JSP configuration in which the prefix had an additional slash.

Old Configuration:

```
<bean
     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="order" value="2" />
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

New configuration:

```
<bean
     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="order" value="2" />
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

In the controller the return path was "/Login/LoginPage.jsp". ( did the change in xml file since there were too much controller methods which returned the jsp file location).

I couldn't trace the issue until log4j was enabled to record the debug issues. The key in identifying the issue was the following line in the logs:

```
2011-10-10 21:38:14.644
[s~exampleapp-test/8.353868453989422042].<stdout>: 16:08:14,644 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views//Login/LoginPage.jsp] in InternalResourceView '/Login/LoginPage'
```

Thanks @Dave for your patience and guidance.