# google app engine: Error: NOT_FOUND

Tags: java, google-app-engine

The app was running well. But after we deployed the version 4, it's showing this error:

> Error: NOT_FOUND

No other message.

You can see it [here](http://pbjtask7.appspot.com/).
While deploying eclipse gives a successful message: *Task7 successfully deployed to Google App Engine*

All the previous versions still run well. The local version also runs okay.
Tried to find similar problems and found a few ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988409/error-not-found-google-apps-eng), [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine-java/NyiOcAYAKXc), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609659/error-after-deploying-the-application-in-appspot?rq=1)) but none of them have any useful solutions.

I don't know whether the web.xml would help to figure out the solution but I am giving it here. Although I checked and found out the web.xml in the previous version (that runs well) and this one is similar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ebiz.pbj.task7.controller.Controller</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>    /start                   </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>    start   </welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>services</param-name>
   <param-value/>
  </init-param>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <filter>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

If you need any other code excerpts please let me know and I'll edit my question.

Really confused about what went wrong suddenly. Any help would be welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: I visited your app but didn't log on. When does your error happen? (immediately after log-on?) Does anything show up in your application log? Is there an error number associated with your error (for example: 404)?

Comment: Yes, immediately after login. In the page it just shows "Error: NOT_FOUND" but the title is "404 NOT_FOUND". In the Logs, no error shows up.

Comment: Since your version 3 works but your version 4 does not, if the GAE/J version that you use has not changed between them then you might have to go through your code changes to find likely candidates of the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Ian Marshall, After I went through the other parts of the code that are done by my other teammates I found the problem.

Comment: I think I should share my findings in case someone else gets into the same problem. This might not be the only cause of the problem because 404: NOT_FOUND can happen for various reasons but this is one of the reasons and people should be aware of it. The naming of the jsp files are case sensitive. In the controller, we have codes like this : if (errors.size() != 0) {
             return "login.jsp";
         }
but our login.jsp was mistakenly named as Login.jsp - so it could not find it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer. You might want to answer your own question and tick it for posterity. (I do remember that there might be a time delay before you can answer your own question, so perhaps you are just waiting for that delay to elapse :).)

Comment: Oh no, I forgot about that option. I'll answer this question. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I should share my findings in case someone else gets into the same problem.

This might not be the only cause of the problem because 404: NOT_FOUND can happen for various reasons but this is one of the reasons and people should be aware of it.

The naming of the jsp files are **case sensitive**. In the controller, we have codes like this :

```
if (errors.size() != 0) 
{ return "login.jsp"; }
```

but our `login.jsp` was mistakenly named as `Login.jsp` - so it could not find it.